# Move player along Y pos

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I've made the move from SpriteKit and Swift to Unity recently, and I've started an Android project. What I want is to move the player up and down so along the Y position only. In xcode I would have simply done this:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let action = SKAction.moveToY(location.y, duration: 0.7)
        action.timingMode = .EaseInEaseOut
        player.runAction(action)
    }
}
```

Would this sort of code translate to C# in the same sort of way? Or does it work differently.

** UPDATE **

This is the code I tried with one of the answers below, but the player is disappearing rather than moving, any suggestions? What I am after is for the player to move to where the screen is tapped, but only on the Y axis. Thanks :)

```
 Vector2 touchPosition;
        [SerializeField] float speed = 1f;   

void Update() {

            for (var i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++) {

                if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began) {

                    // assign new position to where finger was pressed
                    transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x, Input.GetTouch(i).position.y, transform.position.z);

                }
            }    
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can move any object in your scene by calling transform.Translate() from a script on that object, or by getting a reference to another object's transform and calling Translate() on that.

**Move current script's scene object based on finger movement**

```
Vector2 touchDeltaPosition;
[SerializeField] float speed = 1f;

void Update() {

    for (var i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++) {

        if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {

            // get new finger position
            touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(i).deltaPosition;

            // move scene object along y axis
            transform.Translate(0f, -touchDeltaPosition.y * speed, 0f);

        }

    }    

}
```

**Move current script's scene object to finger press location**

```
void Update() {

    for (var i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++) {

        if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began) {

            // assign new position to where finger was pressed
            transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x, Input.GetTouch(i).position.y, transform.position.z);

        }

    }    

}
```

Comment: If the .Moved checks whether the finger has moved across the screen and moves the player with it, would there be a way to move the player to where the screen was tapped along the Y axis too??

Comment: You can use .Began instead of .Moved, as well as .position instead of .deltaPosition.  transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, Input.GetTouch(i).position.y);

Comment: I think I changed the code correctly to what you said, but I've edited my question at the top. The player is disappearing when the screen is tapped.

Comment: Try changing the assignment line to: transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, Input.GetTouch(i).position.y, transform.position.z); also, no need for the Translate() call if changing the position directly. I'll update my answer...

Comment: Just changed the code, the player doesn't disappear anymore but only moves a tiny bit up when you tap the screen, then doesn't move again.

Comment: No. I have updated my question to your edited code. Assuming I've understood your answer correctly, is there anything else I could be doing wrong?? The code I am using is in my original question. The rocket has started disappearing again. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88218/discussion-between-user3071284-and-kellclx).

Answer (score 0):

```
public float speed = 5.0f;

public void Update()
{
    Vector3 moveDelta = new Vector3(0f, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"), 0f);
    transform.Translate(moveDelta * speed * Time.deltatime)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How does the Input.GetAxis translate to a touch location for an Android device?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who needs to know, this is how it worked for me:

public GameObject thingToMove;

```
public float smooth = 2;

private Vector3 _endPosition;

private Vector3 _startPosition;

private void Awake()
{
    _startPosition = thingToMove.transform.position;
}

private void Update()
{
    if(Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android || Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer)
    {
        _endPosition = HandleTouchInput();
    }
    else
    {
        _endPosition = HandleMouseInput();
    }

    thingToMove.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(thingToMove.transform.position, new Vector3(transform.position.x, _endPosition.y, 0), Time.deltaTime * smooth);
}

private Vector3 HandleTouchInput()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++) 
    {
        if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began) 
        {
            var screenPosition = Input.GetTouch(i).position;
            _startPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPosition);
        }
    }

    return _startPosition;
}

private Vector3 HandleMouseInput()
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        var screenPosition = Input.mousePosition;
        _startPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPosition);
    }

    return _startPosition;
}
```

This moves the object to touch location smoothly using .Lerp. More information:
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html